# .onTapGesture problems

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have `StaticTaskListView` which uses a `TaskView` to display a filtered array of tasks. I use the `StaticTaskListView` for the "Done" and "Upcoming" sections of my Task Management app for macOS, and they display the tasks that are checked (have the `isCompleted` value set to true) or unchecked (the opposite).

The `TaskView`:

```
struct TaskView: View {
    @Binding var tasks: [Task]
    @Binding var task: Task
    @Binding var isStrikethrough: Bool
    @State private var isEditingDueDate = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: task.isCompleted ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "stop")
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        task.isCompleted.toggle()
                        print("task.isCompleted: \(task.isCompleted)")
                    }
                }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if isStrikethrough {
                    Text(task.title)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .strikethrough(task.isCompleted)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isStrikethrough.toggle()
                        }
                } else {
                    TextField("New Task", text: $task.title, axis: .vertical)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .strikethrough(task.isCompleted)
                }
            }

            Spacer()
            Text("\(dueDateFormatted)")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .font(.caption)

            Button(action: {
                // Action for showing popover for editing due date
                isEditingDueDate.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $isEditingDueDate) {
                CalendarPopover(task: $task, isEditingDueDate: $isEditingDueDate)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50) // Set popover size as needed
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }

    private var dueDateFormatted: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        return dateFormatter.string(from: task.dueDate)
    }
}
```

As can be seen in the above code, the checkbox icon(`Image(systemName: task.isCompleted ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "stop"`) toggles the `isCompleted` value of a task.

In my `StaticTaskListView`, I access the `TaskView` directly, yet for some reason the checkbox icon is not reacting to tap gestures and updating the `isCompleted` value accordingly, despite this function being controlled by the `TaskView`. Here is this `StaticTaskListview`:

```
struct StaticTaskListView: View {
    let title: String
    let tasks: [Task]
    let toggleAction: (Task) -> Void
    let deleteAction: (Task) -> Void
    let isStrikethrough: Bool

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(tasks) { task in
                TaskView(tasks: .constant([task]), task: .constant(task), isStrikethrough: .constant(isStrikethrough))
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                if let firstIndex = indexSet.first {
                    let taskToDelete = tasks[firstIndex]
                    deleteAction(taskToDelete)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FOR CONTEXT**

What my app looks like ("All" view):

[image]
On the sidebar, you can see the "Done" and "Upcoming" sections, which are the ones that use `StaticTaskListView` to display a filtered array of tasks.

What the "Done" section looks like:

[image]

The `TaskListView`, which is used for the "all" section and works fine (toggles `isCompleted` fine): is here for reference. It also uses the `TaskView` directly:

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    var onDelete: (Task) -> Void
    
    let title: String
    @Binding var tasks: [Task]
    @Binding var isStrikethrough: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach($tasks) { $task in
                    TaskView(tasks: $tasks, task: $task, isStrikethrough: $isStrikethrough)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button(action: {
                                // Handle task deletion here
                                deleteTask(task: task)
                            }) {
                                Text("Delete")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    if let firstIndex = indexSet.first {
                        // Assume that indexSet has only one element for simplicity
                        let taskToDelete = tasks[firstIndex]
                        deleteTask(task: taskToDelete)
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private func deleteTask(task: Task) {
            // Adjust the logic to delete the task
            if let index = tasks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == task.id }) {
                tasks.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
```

**THE DESIRED FUNCTIONALITY**

Below is the desired functionality, shown in a previous version of my app where this functionality was not broken:
[image]

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
The functionality seen in the GIF for the task disappearing and the status being updated globally is already handled in my app, hence it working in the previous version. The only thing that isn't working in my current version is that the checkbox is not reacting to clicks. In this previous version, I did not use `TaskView` directly in the `StaticTaskListView` and instead recreated all the `TaskView` elements in the `StaticTaskListView`, practically duplicating the file. This got tedious to update, hence using an instance of `TaskView` directly in `StaticTaskListView` in the current version.

**THE PROBLEM, SUMMARISED**
Essentially, the only thing that needs to change, and the reason for this post, is fixing the unresponsive checkbox button, allowing it to react to clicks. If anyone can find the source of the problem, that's all I need.

I am new to Swift and to StackOverflow. I understand that my code likely doesn't make too much sense in some places, or that I misuse some features of SwiftUI. If any further clarification or context is required I will provide it.

Comment: You don't share how you define `Task`, so it's hard to know how you expect the UI to detect that its properties have changed. You're also passing a `.constant(task)` into your TaskView, which will deliberately not respond to events that would otherwise induce state changes. In practice, using `.constant()` in production apps (and not in previews) is generally a code smell.

Comment: Get rid of constant, it is a dead end. Only use it in previews

Comment: How would I replace constant?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not actually handling the state of each `Task`. A `@Binding` property will be observed by SwiftUI to carry out view changes as needed, but it isn't responsible for holding on to that state, which is the job of an `@State` property (among others, such as `@ObservedObject`). You're creating `Binding<Task>` objects when you declare the `TaskView`, whereas you should be using the projected value of some state property.

I suspect further up in your view hierarchy you do have some stateful property, and that's why your existing `TaskListView` works. Those `@Binding` properties are observing state changes above.

[This overview of state management in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state) is worth a read.

The main change you need to make is in `StaticTaskListView`, where you declare the tasks as `@State`, or properly pass in state as you had in your old view.

```swift
struct StaticTaskListView: View {
    let title: String
    @State var tasks: [Task]
    let toggleAction: (Task) -> Void
    let deleteAction: (Task) -> Void
    let isStrikethrough: Bool
...
}
```

Comment: My StaticTaskListView used to work, but as soon as I started an instance of TaskView directly in my StaticTaskListView, everything but the checkbox was working. I have never had to use `@State var`. Here is a previous StaticTaskListView, which worked perfectly and showed the functionality in the GIF:
https://pastebin.com/zs4b41Yb